# Angular Material - nested controllers for multiple $mdDialog windows - not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, nested, angular-material

I don't know if I'm simply making a stupid mistake here (for which I apologize in advance). Or there's something that I am missing in terms of AngularJS logic. So, I have a custom $mdDialog, which is triggered by pressing a button. From this $mdDialog, I need to open 2 different $mdDialog windows, depending on the selection that the user makes. This works just fine when keeping the controllers nested in the same parent controller (so because I am working with $mdDialog, I have a lot of controllers).

Once I want to split these controllers for code manageability, I cannot inject them back into the parent controller, and AngularJS is giving me an **Unknown Provider** error.
Here's my index file with the links to the main module and controllers:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/AppController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DatePickController.js"></script>
```

The Angular module:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

The "parent controller" (that triggers the first $mdDialog window):

```
angular
    .module('demoApp')
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'DatePickController', 
    function($scope, $mdDialog, DatePickController){
        $scope.showConfirm = function(event) {
                  $mdDialog.show({
                         targetEvent: event,
                         templateUrl: 'templates/mainDialogTemplate.html',
                         controller: function($scope, $mdDialog, employee){
                         $scope.employee = employee;
                         $scope.closeDialog = function(){$mdDialog.hide();}
                         $scope.pickDate = function(){$mdDialog.show({
                                templateUrl:'templates/calendarDialogTemplate.html',
                                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                                controller: 'DatePickController'
            })
         }
      },
        locals: {employee: $scope.userName}
     })
   };
}])
```

And the "child" controller:
angular
    .module('demoApp')
    .controller('DatePickController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope, $mdDialog){
        $scope.cancel = function(){$mdDialog.cancel();}
        $scope.months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

```
    //Open existing scorecard
    $scope.openScorecard = function(){$mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: 'templates/scorecard.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
            controller: function($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.cancel = function(){
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            }

            $scope.selectMonth = function(){
                $scope.editState = false;
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/saveComments.php',
                    data : employee
                })
            }

            $scope.save = function(){
                $scope.editState = false;
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/saveComments.php',
                    data : employee
                })
            }

            $scope.hide = function(){
                $mdDialog.hide();
            }
        }
     })
   }
}])
```

So what is wrong?

Comment: can you add codepen or plunkr for this?

Comment: Yes, I will add a plunkr later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to inject the controller(s). When you declare them with `angular.controller('name', function() {...})` you specify a name. Now you just use the name to tell which controller the dialog is using.

You are already using the name for the dialog controller `'DatePickController'`. Your `DatePickController` function parameter is not being used, just remove it. Notice the difference, one is a string, the other is a parameter name.